# Stop a floating div from sliding at the the footer

Tags: jquery, html, floating

I have been trying and looking around a while before asking you my question.

I have a floating div that I want to stop at a specific div (footer actually). I know the footer height size.

I tried a lot of code found around the web and Stackoverflow without success. This question has been asked numerous times I know.

Here is the page :
http://www.autohd.fr/A/

The floating div that has to stop when the footer is reached is on the right side "RÉAGIR".

```
$(function() {

var $sidebar = $("#shout"),
    $window = $(window),
    offset = $sidebar.offset(),
    topPadding = 20;

$window.scroll(function() {
    if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
        $sidebar.stop().animate({
            marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
        });
    } else {
        $sidebar.stop().animate({
            marginTop: 0
        });
    }
});
});
```

Thank for your time and help,
Alex

Comment: why don't you post specific examples of the code you are having problems with? it is not clear by simply clicking on your provided link.

Comment: Just did. I guess we can work something out by checking the position of the floating div and the height of the footer... Thx.

Comment: it seems problem originates from your handling of the window scroll event (at the second inline script of the document head). try to debug at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure the that div's bottom doesn't go pass  `$("#footer").offset().top`. You can calculate the current div's bottom like this: `$sidebar.offset().top + $sidebar.height()`. For example:

```
$(function() {
   var $sidebar = $("#shout"),
    $window = $(window),
    offset = $sidebar.offset(),
    topPadding = 20,
    footerTop = $("#footer").offset().top;  // <-- Get the footer's top

   $window.scroll(function() {
    if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
        $sidebar.stop().animate({
            marginTop: Math.min(
                          $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding,
                          footerTop - $sidebar.height()
                       )
        });
    } else {  
        $sidebar.stop().animate({
            marginTop: 0
        });
    }
   });
});
```

Comment: I tried but I get a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;" before "else" is starting. I tried to fix without success. Thx.

Comment: @flintsburg Sorry about that. Fixed now.